# redirecting request to a different listener nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am having two listener 80 and 777. Port 80 act as a reverse proxy. And port 777 does some extra stuff and want to redirect to port 80. How do I redirect to a different port in nginx? I was trying with rewrite but later figured out that it is only used for change of path

```
   ###
   server{
            listen  80;
            server_name     _;
            location / {
                    proxy_pass "http://upstream0;#" is included since links are not allowed in the post
            }

    }

    server{
            listen  777;
            server_name     _;
            #doing some other extra stuf
            //Want to redirect to port 80 under some condition
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
return 302 $scheme://$server_name:80$request_uri;
```

That should do the trick.